Ellipse $c^2=a^2-b^2$
In my textbook the proof for $c^2=a^2-b^2$ for the ellipse (conic section) was written as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Sum of distances from $(0, b)$ to foci} 
&= \text{sum of distances from $(a, 0)$ to foci} \\[4pt]
2\sqrt{b^2 + c^2} &= (a+c) + (a-c) \\[4pt]
\sqrt{b^2 + c^2} &= a \\[4pt]
c^2 &= a^2 - b^2.
\end{aligned}
$$

But I am not sure of how it went from step 1 to step 2. Any help please? Thanks a lot and sorry for any grammar mistake.

Hi, welcome. Don't upload pictures of text; they are hard to read. Just type it out instead. And can you be more specific about what "step 1" and "step 2" are?

I edited the post to replace the image by its text. OP, you can have a look and also make futher changes by clicking the Edit button under your post. It would be great to include more of your thoughts about this in the post.

Also, what are $a$, $b$, and $c$ in the context of a general ellipse (I know, but you should include that in your question)?

$(a+c)+(a-c) = 2a$. Now divide through by $2$.

I think you know that foci lie at $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$. And you know how to compute the distance between two points.

thanks everybody for ht eep I am still kind of new so please forgive my mistakes on this platform

Remember that the definition of the ellipse is the set of all points in the plane $P$ such that the sum of the distances $|PF_1| + |PF_2|$ to each of the focus points is constant.

There are two special points to consider and they give you the two sides of your equation:
At the end of the major axis, at $(a, 0)$:

and at the end of the minor axis $(0, b)$:

In each case connecting the point to both foci at $(\pm c, 0)$ yields line segments, and we can calculate their lengths. In the former case, they lie on the axis so this is straightforward. In the latter case, notice the right triangle and apply Pythagoras/Brahmagupta.
